# How to retrieve the category-specific fields from a facebook page using facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In facebook developers api page it says:

A Page in the Graph API.

The fields shown below are some of the common fields of Facebook Pages. Pages may also contain other (or additional) category-specific fields.

Does anyone know how to retrieve those additional category-specific fields???

I´ve been looking on Internet but not a clue :-(

Answer (score 0):

The doc for the facebook 'page' table shows fields and lists what category of page they are available to:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

For example, the band pages have a 'band_members' field that no other page type has.  You should also check out Facebook Graph API batch requests which you can use to query for something and use the result in a second request using JSONPath notation.  Do a search on this page for JSONPath and you'll see it near the bottom under the 'Specifying dependencies between operations in the request' section:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Hope that helps!

-Kyle